# Issue with creating buttons from select options using jquery

Tags: jquery, button, foreach, drop-down-menu, append

I'm using jquery to make buttons that are connected to my select dropdown options (with the intention of hiding the drop down once these are working), but the loop seems to be iterating multiple times and only the second set are linked to the correct products/variants in the dropdown.

This is the current result: https://www.loom.com/share/37b187b6f24742ea8ef2413d590e5b71?sid=89f3d0e4-6880-4811-87e0-1eba187ae477

[result currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2tjK.png)

The dropdown is built with html and Shopify liquid

Here is the html and liquid for the selector

```
 <select id="product_card_selector" name="id" class="product-variant-select">
      {% for variant in card_product.variants %}
       {% if variant.available %}
        <option value="{{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.title }}</option>
       {% else %}
        <option disabled="disabled">{{ variant.title }} - Sold Out</option>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
  </select>
```

And here is the jquery

```
<script>
  $(function () {

  $('#product_card_selector').each(function (selectIndex, selectElement) {

    var select = $(selectElement);
    var container = $("<div class='radioSelectContainer' />");
    $( ".card-form" ).append(container);
    container.append(select);

    select.find('option').each(function (optionIndex, optionElement) {
      var jqEl = $(optionElement);
      var radioGroup = select.attr('id') + "Group";
      var label = $("<label />");
      container.append(label);

      $('<input type="radio" name="' + radioGroup + '" '+(jqEl.attr("disabled")?'disabled':'')+' />')
          .attr("value", jqEl.val())
          //.click((function () { select.val($(this).val()); })) //radio updates select - see optional below
          .appendTo(label);

      $("<span>" + jqEl.val() + "</span>").appendTo(label);
    });

   
//unchecking when clicking on an already checked radio
    container.find(":radio + span").mousedown(
      function (e) {
        var $span = $(this);
        var $radio = $($span.prev());
        if ($radio.attr("disabled")) return;
        if ($radio.is(':checked')) {
          var uncheck = function() {
            setTimeout(function () { $radio.prop('checked', false); }, 0);
          };
          var unbind = function() {
            $span.unbind('mouseup', up);
          };
          var up = function() {
            uncheck();
            unbind();
          };
          $span.bind('mouseup', up);
          $span.one('mouseout', unbind);
        } else {
          select.val($radio.val());
        }
      }
    );

    select.change((function () { //select updates radio
      $("input[name='" + select.attr('id') + "Group" + "'][value='" + this.value + "']").prop("checked", true);
    }));
  });
});
```

and css

```
<style>
.radioSelectContainer > select {
     /*display: none;*/
}
.radioSelectContainer > label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0.3em 0.3em 0 0;
    background-color:#EFEFEF;
    border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #D0D0D0;
}
.radioSelectContainer > label > span {
    padding:0.2em;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
}
.radioSelectContainer > label > input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
}
.radioSelectContainer > label > input:checked + span {
    background-color:#404040;
    color:#F7F7F7;
}
</style>
```

See above. I've tried several different ways to write the for each statement.